# [http]How to identify end of stream when content-length is not specified?

Tags: node.js, http, stream, content-length, transfer-encoding

First let me show my code.

```
http=require("http");
fs=require("fs");
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var readStream=fs.createReadStream("1.jpg");
    readStream.on("data",function(data){
        res.write(data);
    });
    readStream.on("end",function(data){
        res.write("this string seems not to be sent","utf8");
        res.end("end","utf8");
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

I created a readStream of picture 1.jpg and then sent data stream. After the "end" event was fired, I sent a string "this string seems not to be sent". I didn't specify a content-length in headers.

On the client side, I actually got 1.jpg correctly. But I didn't receive the string. I guess there must be something that marks the end of stream. If so, what the mark is? how it works?

I know that assigning transfer-encoding with "chunked" is a way to send data whose length is uncertain, but my safari shows the response headers are:

Connection  keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding   Identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the client side, I actually got 1.jpg correctly. But I didn't receive the string.

In fact, the string *is* sent. To confirm this:

```
$ echo '(Contents of a JPEG file.)' >1.jpg

$ curl -i http://localhost:3000/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 23 May 2015 08:01:48 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

(Contents of a JPEG file.)
this string seems not to be sentend
```

Your browser (or image viewer) understands the format of a JPEG, so it ignores the extra string at the end. However, it is sent.

> I guess there must be something that marks the end of stream.

Yes. The data is delimited by [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) markers.
`curl` doesn't show them by default, but they're present. To see them in the response:

```
$ curl -i --raw http://localhost:3000/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 23 May 2015 08:23:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

1b
(Contents of a JPEG file.)

20
this string seems not to be sent
3
end
0
```

Comment: Awesome! This is the answer I want.